# Override an override of onLoad(e), but call the lowest base implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, overriding

I have an issue with overriding a method.  I have created a base class with custom code that I want to run during the OnLoad event.  The code in this overridden method applies to 90% of the pages that inherit from it, but on a few pages I need to override the override.  My issue is that I still need to run the System.Web.UI.Page's OnLoad implementation.  If I include the base.OnLoad(e) line in the second class (see below), it calls the BasePageEdit's logic, but if I remove it, the Page_Load event is never called. How can I *skip* over the logic in BaseEditPage's, and still get the functionality from System.Web.UI.Page?

```
public class BasePageEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
     // I need this to raise the Page_Load Event!
     base.OnLoad(e); // Calls System.Web.UI.Page OnLoad Event which I want.

    // Logic that I want to run in ADDITION to base Implementation;

    }

    // Other classes and methods;
}

public class WebPageThatNeedsSpecialOnLoadImplementation : BasePageEdit
{
     protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
     {
     // I need this to raise the Page_Load Event!
     base.OnLoad(e); // If I include this, it runs the BasePageEdit, I don't want that...
     // But I still need to run the System.Web.UI.Page onLoad event or Page_Load will not be called.

     // Logic that I want to run INSTEAD of the logic from the override from BasePageEdit.
     }
}
```

Thank you very much Slaks!  I am editing my question to show how I implemented so that others viewing this post can implement the same way if they choose!

```
public class BasePageEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
    BasePage_OnLoad(e);

    // Logic that I want to run in ADDITION to base Implementation;

    }

    protected virtual void BasePage_OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    // Other classes and methods;
}

public class WebPageThatNeedsSpecialOnLoadImplementation : BasePageEdit
{
     protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
     {
         BasePage_OnLoad(e);

     // Logic that I want to run INSTEAD of the logic from the override from BasePageEdit.
     }
}
```

Comment: that's not possible; create another BaseClass if you have that requirement on many pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that.

However, you can make a new method in `BasePageEdit` which just calls *its* `base.OnLoad`, and call that directly from the derived class instead.